# How to create a composite signal using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

If i have two signals that i generated before, how can i make one composite signal out of them.
From my understanding composite signal is to let the two signals appear on the same plot (overlap)
so what is the syntax need to prodece that composite signal ??

Note: poth signals have the same time interval.

Comment: what is your definition of "composite"? Are your signals additive or multiplicative? Or do you just want to display both signals on the same plot?

Comment: yes just display both signals on same plot thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`hold`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html) function to retain the first plot while you draw the second one over it. Here's an example:

```
x=linspace(0,2*pi,1e3);
plot(x,sin(2*x))
hold on
plot(x,cos(2*x),'r')
hold off
```

`hold off` releases the "hold" and if you plot anything now, the previous plots are not retained. It's good practice to release the hold so that you don't inadvertently keep layering multiple plots (unless of course, that's the intention).

---

If you have two signals of widely ranging amplitudes, one option is to scale them so that they're of comparable amplitudes. This can be achieved for e.g., by normalizing both to a max of 1. E.g.:

```
x=linspace(0,2*pi,1e3);
y=100*sin(2*x);
z=cos(2*x);
plot(x,y/max(abs(y)),x,z/max(abs(z)))
```

You might have to make a note or mention (where ever you're using this) that the signals have been normalized so that it is clear.

Alternately you can use the [`plotyy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html) function which lets you plot two curves with a y-axis for each. E.g.:

```
x=linspace(0,2*pi,1e3);
y=100*sin(2*x);
z=cos(2*x);
plotyy(x,y,x,z)
```

---

EDIT 2:

To change the colors in `plotyy`, you need to use the handles of the lines. Continuing from the above example,

```
[ax,h1,h2]=plotyy(x,y,x,z);
set(h1,'color','m')
set(h2,'color',[0,0.5,0])
```

Here I've shown two ways to set the color. One is using in-built color strings (`'r'` -> red, `'m'` -> magenta, `'c'` -> cyan, `'g'` -> green, `'b'` -> blue, `'y'` -> yellow, `'k'`-> black, `'w'` -> white) and the other is by a 3 element numeric RGB vector which can take values from 0 to 1.

Sometimes, it is desirable to not have the y-axes colored (I don't like them that way). To change them to black, set the value of the `'ycolor'` property for `ax` to black.

```
set(ax,'ycolor','k')
```

Comment: listen it really helped , but i have one more question,  after the i ploted the composte signals,One of the signals has a really big scale(-100-->100) on the y-axis which throws the other signal out of scale (-1-->1) how can i solve this problem

Comment: @Shadi: You can try using the [`plotyy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plotyy.html) command, which plots each curve with a different scale for the y-axis. In this case, there are two y-axes one on the left and one on the right. I'll add in an example.

Comment: @Shadi: No you don't have to use `hold on` and `hold off` in this case. In fact, even with the first example, you can plot it without using hold as `plot(x,sin(2*x),'b',x,cos(2*x),'r')`. I mentioned `hold` because it is a more general solution and will be useful in several other situations.

Comment: you mean plotyy(...) , yoda you have been very helpfull thanks

Comment: yoda , sorry one more, when i run the program with out the colours it works fine but with the colours it gives me an error

Comment: @Shadi: Ah yes, with `plotyy`, I don't think you can set the colors directly. You'll have to use the handles for the lines and set the colors. See the first example in the link to `plotyy` in my comment above. It demonstrates how to use the handles to the plots... If that doesn't help, I'll add an example.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstood, you are looking for something like this:

```
% x and y (of equal length) represent the samples of two signals
% at the same points in time. 
Lx = length(x);
dt = 2;            % Interval between samples (inverse of sampling frecuency).
t = (0:Lx-1) * dt; % This will be the horizontal variable.
plot(t, x, 'b;Signal x;', t, y, 'r;Signal y;');
```